# Distribution of weights in a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, references, conv-neural-network

I am looking for distributions of weights in the neural network as a function of the depth of the layer. Intutively, I expect that near convergence, the deeper layers to have weight matrix will have many near zero values, and a few larger values.

Are there any papers on this subject which you could recommend?

Comment: This is a very broad question - the distribution of weights will depend on many different things: architecture of the net, data, used regularizers (weight decay, dropout, weight/batch normalization etc.) Are you interested in some particular architecture?

Comment: Im interested in the question very generally. Any relevant literature on the subject will be helpful.

Comment: You can easily to that yourself with Keras. It offers a couple of pretrained models, which you can load and easily plot their weights distribution (assuming you are at least a bit familiar with python).